# Facebook Permission Graph API

Tags: php, facebook

```
try {

                    $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/permissions'))->execute(); 
                    $object = $response->getGraphObject() -> asArray(); 
                    echo '<pre>'; 
                    print_r($object);
                    echo '</pre>'; 

                    //problem lies over here
                    for($i = 0 ; $i <count($object['data']); $i++){
                        echo "<br>" . $object['data'][$i] -> permission;
                    }
                } 
                catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) { 
                    echo $ex->getMessage(); 
                    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                    echo $ex->getMessage();
                }
```

Result of print_r($object) is this.
How do i get use a for loop to print out the permission only? count($object['data']) give me an error stating that 'data' is not defined.

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [permission] => user_likes
        [status] => granted
    )

 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [permission] => user_friends
        [status] => granted
    )

 [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [permission] => publish_actions
        [status] => granted
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `data` property when you do `print_r($object)`. Try

```
for($i = 0 ; $i <count($object); $i++){
    echo "<br>" . $object[$i] -> permission;
}
```